# DynamoDB table doesn't display complete attribute value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

The attribute that I'm validating is ~390 chars in length & table displays only 315 chars, cutting off the rest from display. Though when I click on Edit or copy button, all the data is retrieved correctly.

So far I've found that there is limit of 400k per item & its certainly not being crossed here. It seems just an issue with displaying the long attribute value.

Is there a length limit on the attribute value displayed in the table? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: With "display" you mean the AWS Management Console?

Comment: Yes, I'm validating the values in the DynamoDB table using the AWS console.